# Split string with n repetitive elements into n sub-strings

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a string that is a concatenation of m possible types of elements - for the sake of simplicity m = 4 with A, B, C and D.

Whenever there are single elements more than once, I would have to split the string so that there are no repetitions left. However, I would like to generate all possible strings without repetitions.

To make this a little bit clearer, here is an example:
For A B A C D

1. String: A B C D
2. String: B A C D

This gets more complicated when there are several different elements that show up more than once:
For A B A C B D

1. String: A B C D
2. String: A C B D
3. String: B A C D
4. String: A C B D

Is there a smart way to compute this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
vec <- c("A","B","A","C","B","D")
combs <- lapply(setNames(nm = unique(vec)), function(a) which(vec == a))
eg <- do.call(expand.grid, combs)
out <- t(apply(eg, 1, function(r) names(eg)[order(r)]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
# [2,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "D" 
# [3,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
# [4,] "A"  "C"  "B"  "D" 
out
```

First vector:

```r
vec <- c("A","B","A","C","D")
# ...

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
# [2,] "B"  "A"  "C"  "D"
```

If you are starting and ending with strings vice vectors, then know that you can wrap the above with:

```r
strsplit("ABACBD", "")[[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "A" "C" "B" "D"
apply(out, 1, paste, collapse = "")
# [1] "ABCD" "BACD" "ACBD" "ACBD"
```

Comment: @Arne, note the recent edit away from `sapply`, to use `lapply(setNames(...)` instead. The reason is that `sapply` will simplify to a `vector` if all letters occur the same number of times, producing an error with `do.call`. Instead, we force a `list` (which is what `sapply` provides if even one length is different than the others), and `setNames` keeps the letters as names.

Comment: Instead of `lapply(setNames(nm=..), ...)`, I could have done `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`. Six of one, half-dozen of another.